# How prevent circumvention of my intended webpage security?

Tags: php, html

These last few days I managed to get a register and login system working. I got it from [here](https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/12214/login-and-register-using-pdo-php.html).

A user can register with an email and a password. Then the user can go to login and login.

If the login is successful, the user will end up at

> www.mywebpage/Exams/leitfile.html

This works great!

> leitfile.html

has 2 buttons: exam1 and exam2 A click on exam1 opens:

> www.mywebpage/Exams/exam1.html

**My problem:** If someone logs in, they see where they are in the browser address field.

I can put this address directly in a browser and go to:

> www.mywebpage/Exams/exam1.html

**Obviously,** in my ignorance of these things, I am doing something wrong securitywise. I haven't grasped the concept.

How do I prevent direct access without login to a given webpage?

How do I prevent someone who is not logged in opening www.mywebpage/Exams/exam1.html directly?

Maybe some php at the top of exam1.html and exam2.html??

> if (!$_SESSION['success']){ // direct to login ??

(I won't actually put the real exams there until just before exam time, unless I can find some php to redirect from placeholder.html to exam1.html at exam time)

Should I put the login link on the button exam1 and exam2? Change the file permissions??

This is the login.php just for your info. index.php is just a login form with a button whose name="login"

```
<?php
    //start PHP session
    session_start();

    //check if login form is submitted
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        //assign variables to post values
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //include our database connection
        include 'conn.php';

        //get the user with email
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Exams WHERE email = :email');

        try{
            $stmt->execute(['email' => $email]);

            //check if email exist
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                //get the row
                $user = $stmt->fetch();

                //validate inputted password with $user password
                if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
                    //action after a successful login
                    //for now just message a successful login
                    $_SESSION['success'] = 'User verification successful';
                    // added by me direct to the leitfile.html
                    header('location: ../Exams/leitfile.html');
                    exit();
                }
                else{
                    //return the values to the user
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

                    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Incorrect password';
                    header('location: index.php');
                    exit();
                }

            }
            else{
                //return the values to the user
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

                $_SESSION['error'] = 'No account associated with the email';
                header('location: index.php');
            }

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Fill up login form first';
    }

    header('location: index.php');
?>
```

1. Change exam1.html to exam1.php

Would something like this at the top of exam1.php do the job??

```
<?php
if(!$_SESSION['success']) {
    // go back to the login form
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'You must login first to view this page';
    header('location: index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Every page has to check the session variable, and redirect to the login page if it's not set.

Comment: Everything that should be resrtricted to logged in users must be in PHP pages, not HTML pages, so it can check the session.

Comment: So change exam1.html to exam1.php? Can you help me out with the php to check if the session is set?  I guessed I could put it in exam1.php at the top, but maybe it should be somewhere else? I really don't know much about this!!

Comment: It should be `if (isset($_SESSION['success']))`, but otherwise just as you wrote in the question.